# Fit Sketch Artboards on Every device in Framer.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, framerjs

I have a prototype built, imported from Sketch with multiple artboards that are 640x1136. But I would like it to fit on all devices when I run it in Framer. Right now it only fits on iPhone 5 resolution. What do I need to do in order for the prototype to work on all devices?

I tried making each artboard larger, with the content centered, and then ran `Framer.Device.fullScreen = true`, but the proportions are still off. Is there a way to use percentages rather than static pixel positions so the views will fit in each device accordingly?

Attached is screenshot of what it looks like on 6+ (don't fit), and what it looks like on a 5 (fits).
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I use this to scale my Sketch artboards to fit Framer's device

```
artboardWidth = 640
Framer.Device.contentScale = (Screen.width / artboardWidth)
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! Still doesn't show up right in the framer app on Android tho :/

Comment: works beautifully on desktop! not so much on my iOS device.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, removing the sketch artboard solved it for me...